# Simple Popover Example Causing: "Cannot read property 'na' of undefined"

Tags: lightning, javascript, slds, javascript-controller, popover

I'm trying to get the popover example from the Salesforce documentation working and it's giving me an interupt error with "Cannot read property 'na' of undefined" message.

All I have done is copy from: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation

Have I missed something obvious? 
Thanks[image]

App

```
    <aura:application description="PopoverApp" extends="force:slds" access="GLOBAL" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <c:PopoverCmp />
</aura:application>
```

Component

```
<aura:component description="PopoverCmp">
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button name="popover" label="Show Popover" onclick="{!c.handleShowPopover}"/>
    <div class="mypopover" onmouseover="{!c.handleShowPopover}">Popover should display if you hover over here.</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
handleShowPopover : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
        body: "Popovers are positioned relative to a reference element",
        referenceSelector: ".mypopover",
        cssClass: "popoverclass, cMyCmp"
    }).then(function (overlay) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            //close the popover after 3 seconds
            overlay.close(); 
        }, 3000);
    });
}
})
```

CSS

```
    .THIS.popoverclass {
    min-height: 100px;
}

.THIS.no-pointer .pointer{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the component, in `aura:application` or using component in record page with app builder?

Comment: Hi Raul, I'm just using a basic app. I can add it to the description ..one second

Comment: Last time I checked `lightning:overlayLibrary` was not supported in `aura:application`

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. Let me try another way.. thanks for your input

Comment: Hi Raul, it works when I use it with lightning app builder so I think you're right. Feel free to add it as an answer and I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lightning:overlayLibrary` does not work in `aura:application`.

Use component inside any component in app builder, where it works.